# Drupal Views from Feeds

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-feeds

I have setup a feeds importer to grab news from another site. It has the built in block that's working just fine. Now I need to customize the output. How do I add more fields to the block? Tried with Views, which is kinda working, but it's not updating. 
Anyone had any success making a view from the feed?

Answer (score 0):

Have you already try to use the Agregator Module ?

I've already have a similar problem, just by "mix" Aggregator & Feeds modules and, works fine.

http://drupal.org/project/feeds > It provide a import/aggregate many supports as XML, RPC, OPML, CSV, ATOM and more ...

Comment: Yes, I am using the Aggregator to pull the feed. The problem is, it's not updating on cron run, only manually, which is not an option.